# Cant load a xml with java as I need it (Beginner)

Tags: java, xml

Hello I am pretty new to coding, and I struggle a little with reading xml files right now.
I am also pretty new in Stackoverflow so sorry if this post is wrong.
So I got the following code:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document config = builder.parse(new File(path + name));

    NodeList nList = config.getElementsByTagName("title");

    for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node Items = nList.item(i);
        Element ItemElement = (Element) Items;
        lines[i][0] = ItemElement.getElementsByTagName("content").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Content").getNodeValue();
        color[i][0] = ItemElement.getElementsByTagName("content").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Color").getNodeValue();
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The XML i want to read is:

```
<Config>
    <title>
        <content Color="green" Content="Hallo"/>
        <content Color="red" Content="Hallo"/>
    </title>
</Config>
```

Now the problem is that in the end there will be up to 30 lines with content
but it only reads the first line and ignores the other line.
Except when I write it like that:

```
<Config>
    <title>
        <content Color="green" Content="Hallo"/>
    </title>
    <title>
        <content Color="red" Content="Hallo"/>
    </title>
</Config>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Variable names should start with a lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase.

Comment: `ItemElement.getElementsByTagName("content").item(0)` obviously only gets you the first (index `0`) element. If you want all the other elements simply change the argument for `item(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking a loop around the node list returned by `ItemElement.getElementsByTagName("content")`. You can fix it e.g. as follows

```
      for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node item = nList.item(i);
        Element itemElement = (Element) item;
        final NodeList contentNodes = itemElement.getElementsByTagName("content");
        for (int j = 0; j < contentNodes.getLength() ; j++) {
          lines[i][j] = contentNodes.item(j).getAttributes()
              .getNamedItem("Content").getNodeValue();
          color[i][j] = contentNodes.item(j).getAttributes()
              .getNamedItem("Color").getNodeValue();
        }
      }
```

Remark:

- variable names in Java should start with lowercase letter, e.g. `Items` -> `items`, `ItemElement` -> `itemElement`